# Invoking Mail App on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

The application I'm writing calls a web service that sends an email to the user. After the call to the web service is complete, I would like to bring up the Mail application so the user can read the email. I know I can use mailto:, but then a new email is created for the user to compose. Is there a way to invoke the Mail application so that it starts up at the Mailboxes view, allowing the user to navigate to their inbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it. There is no functionality in the SDK to bring up another application outside of URL associations. The best you can hope for in the short term is that they create a way for you to embed an email panel into your application.